# What's the correct way to set up a network with multiple upstream routers?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, vlan, opnsense

I have a physical network topology that goes from

- Modem, to

  - OPNSense Router (subnet 192.168.0.0/24), to

    - L2 Managed Network Switch, to

      - Various LAN clients, including
      - TP-Link Router (subnet 192.168.1.0/24)

I'll be referencing port numbers indicated in this topology diagram:
[image]

The reason I have a secondary router (TP-Link Router) is so that I can have a dedicated VPN client upstream and bypass my service's 5-client limit. This is an intended use of the credentials; the service is ExpressVPN, who advertise directly on their site the ability (and, indeed, how-to guides) for setting up their OpenVPN implementation on a router to allow more than 5 devices to use their service at a time (including IoT devices and other devices that can't connect directly). In my use case, I want to be able to selectively assign devices to one router or the other to either make use of the VPN or not.

I have the TP-Link Router configured with OpenVPN, and any devices that connect to it wirelessly are connecting to the VPN as expected

The issue I'm running into is with configuring wired devices to use the secondary router as their upstream. I have the switch configured so that the secondary router uses a LAN port on the switch as an upstream (LAN1), and a WAN port on the switch as a downstream (UP2). I had thought that putting UP2 and specific LAN devices (ie LAN3, LAN5) into a separate VLAN would allow those wired clients to use the secondary router for their WAN connection, but when I try this the LAN devices lose connection to the Internet and both subnets entirely, even after an ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew cycle

Broadly, I'm wondering how to correctly configure my topology (at both a software and hardware level) so that I can use the secondary router as an upstream for specific LAN devices

- I've assigned the secondary router a static IP from the OPNSense router that's showing up as the secondary router's WAN address, as expected
- Devices that connect wirelessly to the secondary router have full internet access and full access to the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet

Comment: so you have devices on the WAN-side of the TPlink and you want them to forward traffic through it like they were on the LAN-side of it? that's not going to work. do you want all stations to use the VPN when connecting to the Internet or just some of them? also one tip, if you are going to be using VPNs, avoid default IP ranges like 192.168.0.0/24 or 192.168.1.0/24.

Comment: Not exactly, the TPLink WAN is connected to one of the LAN ports on the switch, and one of its LAN ports is connected to a WAN port on that same switch. My thinking is that the flow should go modem -> OPNSense -> NetSwitch -> TPLink -> NetSwitch again, so that the WAN port on the Switch that the TPLink router is connected to can be used as a separate upstream

Comment: The problem here is that you want your wired clients to be on a different IP network than the LAN of the router, but there is no router to act as a default gateway on 192.168.0.0/24 that can reach 192.168.1.0/24. Switches don't typically have a WAN, so that's probably an uplink port, but it doesn't do routing. if you have more than one IP network represented amongst devices on a switch, they will only be able to contact other devices within their particular IP network. you could however put the TPLink between the switch and OPNSense router, and switch the gateway on a device you want to VPN.

Comment: Another alternative is to set up a VPN server that establishes your OpenVPN connection, configure it for forwarding, and just point clients default gateway to it when you want to use the VPN. Unfortunately in either scenario, the default gateway is the only configuration you have available to "elect" to use the VPN (or not), if you want full VPN protection for traffic going to the Internet. It is possible to use proxies and ALGs to route traffic into a tunnel, if that is preferable, but there will likely be leaks related to applications not honoring proxy configuration.